# How to resolve Java heap space with htmlunit

Tags: java, multithreading, htmlunit, heap-memory

We have a multi-threaded application that is used to crawl data from various websites. We use htmlunit to download the content for some of the websites. 
The issue of Out of memory error has suddenly started to come. Our application uses 30 threads in the deployment server.

We are using following in our deployments:

```
htmlunit-2.12.jar
htmlunit-core-js-2.12.jar
Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
```

For tomcat we use following parameters:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx3584m 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Running on:
CentOS release 6.3 (4GB RAM)

From various suggestion on Java heap memory related to htmlunit, I have tried:

1. Changing from Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment to OpenJDK Runtime Environment.
2. Used webClient.closeAllWindows(); where ever required.

Have found no luck with these changes. The application uses entire heap in under 10 minutes.
How can we overcome this Out of Memory error issue ?

**Edit:** After updating to htmlunit-2.16.jar we get improvement in garbage collection. (along with OpenJDK)

[image]

Before:(With htmlunit-2.12.jar and Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15))
[image]

Is version of htmlunit causing problem ?

**Edit**
In the legacy code of the application, webClient were not being closed in some particular case, which caused webClient objects to be created and hence heap size increased. But even after closing the webclient and making it null, the heap space issue persists.

How to resolve this memory heap issue?

Comment: 4GB RAM seems fairly low for a high performance web application.  Can you increase to 8GB or even 16GB?

Comment: We had the same implementations with 2 GB of RAM and 20 threads and we never noticed high CPU like this before.

Comment: Looking at your code below `new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 40, 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue)` you are using 20 threads until the queue reaches it's capacity. After that the number of threads can increase to 40.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the data as you crawl?

Are you keeping it all in an in-memory model? Or are you writing to disk / database as you go?

If keeping it all in memory that's likely the problem.

Also, are you processing just text / html or are you also processing images?

Comment: We write it to a database as soon as we fetch the result.

Comment: Can I see a snippet of code that submits the tasks to the thread pool? Are you loading images into memory (ByteArrayInputStream)?

Comment: We do not download any images while crawling. We use ThreadPoolExecutor to exceute threading.  
`ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)`

Comment: CAN I SEE A SNIPPET OF CODE THAT SUBMITS TASKS TO THE THREAD POOL?

Comment: `public class Application(){

 static ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 40, 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);

 public void method(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   executor.execute(new FetcherThread("FetcherThread_"+i));
  }
 }

}



class FetcherThread extends Thread {

  public boolean isFetching() { return fetchStatus; }

  public FeedBasedFetcherThread(String name) {
   super(fetcherThreadGroup, name);
  }

  public void run() {
  
  //fetch html and update db
  
  }

} `

Comment: Why is your task extending `Thread`? It should implement `Runnable` or `Callable`. You already have all the Threads you need (ie your thread pool)

Comment: That is legacy code. Trying to figure why it was put at first place.

Comment: Even after updating to implement Runnable we found same issue.

Comment: How many tasks do you create in total? If there's millions you might need to block on a `CountDownLatch` before submitting the task.